# Linear regression in a list with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of 'steps' that form a ramps series. Eeach step has a `start value`, an `end value` and a `duration`. Here is an example plot:

[image: Example plot of a list of steps]

It is guaranteed, that the start value of a subsequent step is equal to the end value. Its a monotonous function.

Now I need to get the value at a given time. I have already a working implementation using good old foreach but I wonder if there is some clever way to do it with `linq`. Perhaps someome has an idea to substitute the `GetValueAt` function?

```cs
class Program
{
    class Step
    {
        public double From { get; set; }
        public double To { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var steps = new List<Step>
        {
            new Step { From =  0, To = 10, Duration = 20},
            new Step { From =  10, To = 12, Duration = 10},
        };

        const double doubleTolerance = 0.001;
        // test turning points
        Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(GetValueAt(steps, 0) - 0) < doubleTolerance);
        Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(GetValueAt(steps, 20) - 10) < doubleTolerance);
        Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(GetValueAt(steps, 30) - 12) < doubleTolerance);
        // test linear interpolation
        Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(GetValueAt(steps, 10) - 5) < doubleTolerance);
        Debug.Assert(Math.Abs(GetValueAt(steps, 25) - 11) < doubleTolerance);
    }

    static double GetValueAt(IList<Step> steps, int seconds)
    {
        // guard statements if seconds is within steps omitted here
        var runningTime = steps.First().Duration;
        var runningSeconds = seconds;

        foreach (var step in steps)
        {
            if (seconds <= runningTime)
            {
                var x1 = 0; // stepStartTime
                var x2 = step.Duration; // stepEndTime

                var y1 = step.From; //  stepStartValue
                var y2 = step.To; // stepEndValue

                var x = runningSeconds;
                // linear interpolation
                return y1 + (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1) * (x - x1);  
            }
            runningTime += step.Duration;
            runningSeconds -= step.Duration;
        }

        return double.NaN;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try `Aggregate`:

```
static double GetValueAt(IList<Step> steps, int seconds)
{
    var (value, remaining) = steps.Aggregate(
        (Value: 0d, RemainingSeconds: seconds),
        (secs, step) =>
        {
            if (secs.RemainingSeconds > step.Duration)
            {
                return (step.To, secs.RemainingSeconds - step.Duration);
            }
            else
            {
                return (secs.Value + ((step.To - step.From) / step.Duration) * secs.RemainingSeconds, 0);
            }
        });

    return remaining > 0 ? double.NaN : value;
}
```

Comment: Ah, the idea to combine Aggregate with tuples never occored to me. Thanks for the great idea!

Answer (score 1):

let's ignore linq for a moment...

for small amounts of steps, your foreach approach is quite effective ... also if you can manage the accessing side to favor ordered sequential access instead of random access, you could optimize the way of accessing the required step to calculate the value... think of an iterator that only goes forward if the requested point is not on the current step

if your amount of steps becomes larger and you need to access the values in a random order, you might want to introduce a balanced tree structure for searching the right step element

Comment: Thanks you! I was just wondering, if a linq approach would be possible. Perhaps the foreach approach is better readable for others as well.